# Microsoft Graph What permissions need for getting events another user

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

using code below to inject graph client:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(configuration.AzureActiveDirectory)))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
.AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(configuration.MicrosoftGraph)))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I dont understand what i am doing wrong. I need to get events of another user by graph

`var events = await Graph.Users[Email].Calendars[calendarId].Events.Request().GetAsync();`

This is working only for current user but if i try to use it for another user I get this error:

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
ClientRequestId: d1903ca9-1a96-4704-bc9c-35c01f557bf1
```

here my permissions
[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: `Check credentials and try again` so how do you initialize your `await Graph`?

Comment: hi @TinyWang
`services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(configuration.AzureActiveDirectory)))
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(configuration.MicrosoftGraph)))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add Delegated API permission and test it again(in your screenshot, the `Calendars.Read` is Application type). Please wait for several minutes for the newly added permission to take effect.

[image]

If you don't want to add other permissions, or adding delegated API permission still doesn't work, then I'm afraid you have to use client credential flow to authorize t he graph client.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var events = await graphClient .Users[Email].Calendars[calendarId].Events.Request().GetAsync();
```